# Printing doubles of fixed size in Java

Tags: java

I have a matrix as follows (e.g):

```
1 2
1000000000000 3.15
```

I want to print it to a string in a way that it is properly tabulated, with each entry taking up exactly 8 places:

```
1.000000    2.000000
1.00e006    3.150000
```

I have been researching DecimalFormat, NumberFormat and figured out a way of doing it with a specific function coded by myself, but it fails when a number is written using decimal notation.
Any way of printing a double to a string taking up a specified number of spaces no matter how it is written (regular or scientific notation)?

Comment: Have you tried `System.out.printf`?

Comment: I want to actually convert it to a String, not printing it out on the screen. Sorry for not making it clear, I have just edited ;)

Comment: `String.format`, which uses the exact same formatter as `System.out.printf`.

Comment: So it's a matrix of Strings and you want to format it to a String with 8 characters? So if it's shorter, you want it padded with space and if it's longer, it is truncated? Can you give an example of the input and the expected output you want?

Comment: `DecimalFormat,` of course. It doesn't print numbers in scientific notation.

Comment: @anonymous Just editted.

Comment: What about the sign of the exponent?

Comment: @user2891462 have you looked into this? http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.text/display-numbers-in-scientific-notation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this? You can uses a regex to remove the sign if you want. This may need some more work.

```
public static String formatScientific(double val) {
    // Default case.
    String out = String.format("%1.6f", val);

    // Use scientific notation on values greater than 10. 
    if (val >= 10)
        out = String.format("%1.2e", val).replaceAll("\\+", "").concat("0");

    return out;
}
```

Output:

```
1.000000
2.000000
1.00e120
3.150000
```

**Edit**: I should have check for `val >= 10`, not `val >= 10^2` oops...

Comment: Thank you, I finally used a similar approach and relaxed the restrictions :)